# output from AbsoluteTiming

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This is just a curiosity - I don't have a real question.
The output of AbsoluteTiming has a definite pattern; can anyone confirm/explain ?

```
xxx = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 10^6];

Sin[#] & /@ xxx; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0890089, Null} *)

Max[Exp[#] - 0.5, 0] & /@ xxx; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.1560156, Null} *)

$Version
8.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (February 23, 2011)
```

Comment: If would be good if you made your question explicit and very clear for the sake of those who will come across it in the future.  The same goes for answers as well ...

Comment: That's still a question - can we confirm or explain this behaviour? It's just not a problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Documentation, "`AbsoluteTiming` is always accurate down to a granularity of `$TimeUnit` seconds, but on many systems is much more accurate." So evaluating `$TimeUnit` probably can elucidate this issue.

Comment: @b.gatessucks What you get by evaluating `$TimeUnit` on your machine?

Answer (score 2):

Yep. Let´s check if the time quantum is consistent:

```
Differences@
 Round[10^5 Sort@
    Union[AbsoluteTiming[
         Sin[#] & /@ 
           RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], #];][[1]] & /@ 
      RandomInteger[10^6, 100]]]

(*
-> {1562, 1563, 1563, 1562, 1562, 1563, 1563, 1562, 1562, 1563, 1563, \
    1562, 1562, 1563, 1563, 1562, 1562}
*)
```

**Edit**

Better code

```
Differences@
 Sort@Union[
   Round[10^5 AbsoluteTiming[
         Sin[#] & /@ 
           RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], #];][[1]] & /@ 
     RandomInteger[10^6, 100]]]
```

Comment: I get {0.0710041, Null} and {0.1250072, Null} plus {100, 0, 300, 400, 300, 200, 300, 200, 100, 0, 200, 0, 500, 100, 100, \
100, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 200, 0, 100, 200, 200, 400, 100, 200, 100, 100, \
100, 0, 100, 0, 300, 100, 200, 0, 200, 0, 100, 0, 200, 500, 300, 200, \
0, 400, 0, 0, 600, 200, 200, 100, 200, 201, 200, 300, 100, 100, 100, \
100, 0, 600, 300, 100, 500, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 700, 200, 200, \
300, 100, 0, 200, 900, 300, 400}

Comment: and I get (on windows 7, M V8.01) {100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 400, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 100, 100, 400, \
100, 0, 100, 0, 300, 0, 100, 200, 200, 0, 0, 100, 0, 200, 200, 0, \
200, 0, 100, 200, 0, 100, 200, 100, 300, 200, 0, 300, 100, 100, 100, \
100, 0, 100, 0, 0, 600, 100, 300, 500, 0, 300, 200, 200, 200, 200, \
100, 401, 0, 200, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 200, 200, 100, 100, 300, \
0, 100, 0, 200, 100, 200, 0, 0, 300, 100, 1100, 2400}

Comment: @Sjoerd Just curious ... in my machine the code always returns a clean and sorted list of non-repeating integers ... Can you check where the bug is?

Comment: I get {18, 67, 113, 117, 75, 18, 33, 117, 75, 274, 416, 60, 47, 9, 16, 77, \
145, 11, 89, 72, 160, 63, 27, 325, 154, 4, 398, 21, 22, 104, 52, 41, \
64, 24, 160, 27, 158, 94, 123, 46, 29, 182, 55, 2, 62, 0, 175, 75, \
31, 147, 265, 50, 24, 18, 34, 39, 112, 158, 291, 134, 139, 245, 96, \
345, 229, 151, 33, 10, 342, 33, 101, 66, 228, 34, 490, 66, 461, 79, \
8, 169, 485, 91, 71, 35, 78, 89, 274, 192, 4, 85, 185, 211, 367, 170, \
226, 176, 304, 13, 347} on Linux 64 bit. Seems a Windows only feature.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your system's clock only has granularity to some fraction of a second that happens to produce a repeating decimal. I have never noticed this on my Macs.
It's cool, though.

**EDIT**
Now that I am home I can confirm this must be system-specific: here is my output from the code in belisarius's answer:

```
{56, 119, 28, 25, 33, 397, 35, 82, 185, 67, 41, 67, 218, 192, 115, \
28, 74, 16, 187, 222, 194, 8, 129, 399, 68, 75, 71, 34, 5, 37, 62, \
64, 137, 173, 24, 98, 135, 308, 63, 155, 208, 861, 22, 72, 72, 184, \
609, 564, 112, 1011, 118, 81, 158, 90, 351, 33, 35, 68, 10, 126, 39, \
194, 7, 108, 278, 75, 37, 214, 34, 166, 119, 10, 335, 141, 4, 988, \
90, 121, 71, 130, 117, 186, 33, 123, 111, 110, 57, 64, 213, 217, 210, \
204, 98, 247, 20, 1421, 28, 2003, 353}
```